# RSpec mock passed to Array() causes error in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
# expected
Array(Object.new) # => [Object.new]
Array([Object.new]) # => [Object.new]

# but when using an rspec mock
it = RSpec::Mocks::Mock.new
it.respond_to?(:to_a) # => false
Array(it) # => RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Mock received unexpected message :to_a with (no args)
```

This only happens in 1.9.2.

It seems the Array method is calling `to_a` even though the mock can't respond.

The work around is this:

```
[it].flatten # => [it]
```

Is the fault with the Rspec mock or the [Array method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Array)? The docs for Kernal#Array suggest it calls `.to_ary` then `.to_a`, but the mock responds to neither so should it just be wrapped in an array like other objets are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in newer versions of RSpec.